# Evaluation of Bayes GARCH estimation

Tags: r, bayesian, garch, model-evaluation

I am using the bayesGARCH package to estimate Bayesian GARCH models and I was wondering how to evaluate them in terms of precision of forecast or at least the quality of the model.

I have encountered a KLIC criterion, but I do not know, how to employ that for bayesGARCH model.